# C++ concepts with variadic templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

I've returned to c++ after many years and trying to grasp the concepts. I've written a simple test code, but I'm getting an error which I don't really understand why it is here.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
concept addable = requires (T a, U b)
{
    a + b;
};

template <typename T>
T test_add(T&& value)
{
    return value;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto test_add(T&& value, Args&&... rest) requires addable<T, decltype(test_add(forward<Args>(rest)...))>
{
    return value + test_add(forward<Args>(rest)...);
}
```

The goal is to check if there is a valid + operation on the returning expression, but when i call the function like this:

```
auto result = test_add(1, 3, 5);
```

I get following error: "no instance of overloaded function "test_add" matches the argument list".

What is wrong here?

Comment: `test_add` is not variadic; it only takes one argument.

Comment: The compiler should explain _why_ in the rest of the error message. This is just one part of it.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas there are 2 overloads, one of which is variadic

Comment: At the point of concept instantiation, the function has not even finished its declaration; therefore the second parameter doesn't exist and triggers a hard error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want the `concept` to be variadic, so you need a parameter pack and then a fold expression over the `+` operator:

```cpp
template <class... Ts>
concept addable = requires(Ts&&... ts) { (... + ts); };
//                                        ^^^^^^^^
//                                        fold over +
```

Your `test_add` function templates could then be replaced with *one* that uses the `concept` (with a similar fold expression):

```
auto test_add(addable auto&&... values) {
    return (... + std::forward<decltype(values)>(values));
}
```

---

If you want two separate function templates, you can (with the same `concept` as above). You mainly need to change what you put in as a requirement:

```cpp
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) test_add(T&& value) {
    return std::forward<T>(value);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto test_add(T&& value, Args&&... rest)
    requires addable<T, Args...>
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    return std::forward<T>(value) + test_add(std::forward<Args>(rest)...);
}
```

Comment: The proposed solution is nice but I'm wondering why op syntax would be wrong? The intent is clear (which does not mean that it is valid C++) but I don't understand [compilers returned errors](https://godbolt.org/z/EEq1EqxT5). They tell they don't find the 2 arguments version of ```test_add``` as if they cannot recurse.

Comment: @Oersted Yes, your 3 argument version `requires` the two argument version to already have been seen. You could possible get out of that trap with a forward declaration (like `template <class T, class... Args> auto test_add(T&& value, Args&&... rest) -> std::common_type_t<T, Args...>;`) before the definition with the constraint, but that feels awkward (if it even works properly in all cases).

Comment: Thanks, I see your point but it feels like an issue that you can define a variadic template function by compile-time recursion but not recur on the requirement...

Comment: @Oersted You're welcome! I suggest you leave the question open for awhile to attract more answers. Perhaps someone that knows the formal reason better than I do comes along and provides a motivation for _why_ it is like that.

Comment: @Oersted Oh, it wasn't your Q :-) Ok, then my recommendation goes to the OP.

Comment: Actually I would've asked the same questions :D Thanks for your answers and i'll leave the question for a while.